# ionic sincronização offile

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic3

Boa Tarde... Preciso desenvolver um app em ionic que seja offline (pouchDB) e quando tivesse conexão com a rede local no meu caso (wifi) fizesse a integração com o servidor que no meu caso seria um tablet central e os demais tablets se comunicariam com ele até onde sei existe o couchDB mais ele é usado em servidor e no meu caso o servidor seria um tablet como fazer isso? tem como instalar o couchDB em um tablet? ou existe outras maneiras?

Comment: Cara não parece uma boa ideia utilizar um tablet como servidor

Comment: É que tem um aplicativo chamado praticScore que ele faz isso... tem a rede local que é uma  antena de wifi.... tem o tablet master e os demais lançam resultado e esse master vê em tempo real... sem ter internet só por estarem conectados a rede local.. não sei se fui claro

Comment: Enfim, não tem como rodar o couchDB no tablet, pelo menos o software não é compatível, o que daria pra vc fazer é enviar pra esse tablet(master) e ele enviar pra algum servidor(PC) com o couchDB. Mas isso também não seria uma boa ideia, o ideal era vc ter um servidor(PC) e enviar os dados dos dispositivos pro mesmo, você poderia trabalhar com perfis pra exibir tudo nesse tablet centra e os demais teriam outro perfil

Comment: mais o pouchDB sincroniza com um banco couchDB que ambos são JSON será que o pouchDB não funciona com outro banco JSON?

Comment: Sim, mas é necessário um SO compatível pra instalar o couchDB, no caso o Android não é compatível. O que você pode fazer se quer seguir esse modelo é não usar o pouchDB, em vez disso usa o SQLite e implementa você mesmo a sincronização na mão.

Comment: mais como que os tablets iriam conversar.. Como que acessaria o localhost desse tablet master?

Comment: Você apontaria as requisições pro ip dele

Comment: e como eu pegaria esses dados ?